# ext4_orphan_cleanup errors on LVM

Tags: linux, debian, lvm

I'm running a server with Debian 7.2 on a RAID 1 with two drives with LVM on top and I keep getting these messages in my syslog. Should I be concerned? Is this a bug? What could it be deleting?

```
Feb 23 23:00:05 ltsp kernel: [312745.708283] EXT4-fs (dm-2): orphan cleanup on readonly fs
Feb 23 23:00:05 ltsp kernel: [312745.708795] EXT4-fs (dm-2): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 785414
Feb 23 23:00:05 ltsp kernel: [312745.709705] EXT4-fs (dm-2): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 261919
Feb 23 23:00:05 ltsp kernel: [312745.714217] EXT4-fs (dm-2): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 1702834
Feb 23 23:00:05 ltsp kernel: [312745.716226] EXT4-fs (dm-2): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 414859
Feb 23 23:00:05 ltsp kernel: [312745.716246] EXT4-fs (dm-2): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 414716
Feb 23 23:00:05 ltsp kernel: [312745.716978] EXT4-fs (dm-2): ext4_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode 405397
```

This is happening around the time I'm taking a snapshot and removing it, are these normal messages when removing a snapshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this for sure has nothing to do with snapshot removal, but for taking it instead and it's ok — logs show journal replaying messages.